# Application that use a lot of MP3 files?

Tags: android

I have a general doubt about how to design Android apps that use a lot of MP3 (or other audio) files. My problem is that I do not know what is the best way/location to store such files. 
I know that these options are available:

1. Store them on a remote server and fetch via gprs/wifi on demand (like, on a button click)
2. Store them locally inside the app (taking care they do not exceed the max size)
3. Store them locally on the sdcard (a user could delete them)
4. Store them both remote and locally

Could you tell me what is the best way to do? Also, if you store these files locally, do you download them after a user installs an app or you use some other method?

For example, my last app had approx 400MB of MP3 files and I was in a deep doubt where to store them. I chose remote web server, but I am not sure that was the right choice.

Thanks in advance

Comment: 400MB ? Do you realize even the biggest game apps don't take more than 50MB ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm interested in how you convince people to download 400MB of Music-files. You should compress them.

I would store them on the SDcard. If the user deletes them -> His problem (you could give him a message). But streaming them is a bad idea because if the user has no connection, he can't hear anything.

Downloading the files after the user installed the App (like the "Need for Speed Shift"-App) would be an option, too. In this case, you would save them on the SDcard, too.

Comment: The full storage is 400MB. A user will get the file he needs only (approx 1MB).

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea. I would ship all Music-files with the App (but not if it's 400MB) or download the whole Sound-Source (like Need for Speed Shift) and store it on the SDcard. Otherwise, you'll need to see if you can compress the files more or leave some of them out. 400MB is huge.

Comment: What do you mean under "compressing these audio files"? Does Android SDK has such tool or you were referring to some external tool?

Comment: You said you use MP3-files. Simply compress those files (by choosing a lower Bitrate). Sounds for `onClick`-Actions mustn'd have a good quality.

Comment: These files will be played (this was a joke-kind app) at the phone's external speakers. Have you made such apps? Any suggestion what is the lowest bit rate possible to have without losing the quality?

Comment: Compressing MP3 without loosing quality doesn't come along. But speakers on phones are mostly very poor things, so you'll be able to compress them to 92kbps (or even less).